# List any integer that is divided by five or six

Tags: java, integer

The directions are the following:  read in the starting and ending integer number , display all numbers (inclusive) divisible by both 5 and 6 print 10 per line. The tenth number should be the number then a new line. Don't prompt to read in the starting and ending integer number.
Always output a new line after printing out all the numbers.

When I submit the assignment, it doesn't meet all the requirements. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Exercise4_10M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = 1 ;

   int k = input.nextInt();

     for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {

       if (i%5==0&&i%6==0)

       System.out.print((count++ % 10 != 0) ? i + " ": i + "\n" );

    }
    System.out.println("");

}

     }
```

Comment: Seperate the number processing from output ie: calculate all the numbers and cache them in an array. Then loop through the results, printing 10 at a time on each line..

Answer (score 3):

> *read in the starting and ending integer number*

You only read one number (and using as the ending integer number)

Answer (score 1):

> Don't prompt to read in the starting and ending integer number.

From my understanding you need to pass the numbers as arguments to the application, i.e. like this:

```
java Exercise4_10M 100 300
```

Those would then be written to the `args` parameter of `main(...)`, i.e. it would look like this:

```
args = {"100","300"}
```

That would require you to check the number of parameters, parse them into integers and possibly account for switched parameters (i.e. what if they were `300 100`?).

As a sidenote: `System.out.println("");` - if you just want to write a newline, the `""` parameter isn't needed.